# Increase height of rows with combined cells in tabular environment

Tags: tables

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.75cm, right=2.75cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pbox}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\definecolor{UniBlue}{RGB}{0,102,204}
\definecolor{UniOrange}{RGB}{255,128,0}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{(#1)}}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{chemfig, upgreek, siunitx, chemformula, enumitem} % PACKAGES GERARDO
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Hoja7'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Research schedule for the project.}
  \rotatebox{90}{
  \scalebox{0.8}{
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Activity / Term }}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{2022}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{2023}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{2024}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{2025}} \\
\cline{2-13}          & \textbf{Summer} & \textbf{Fall } & \textbf{Winter} & \textbf{Summer} & \textbf{Fall } & \textbf{Winter} & \textbf{Summer} & \textbf{Fall } & \textbf{Winter} & \textbf{Summer} & \textbf{Fall } & \textbf{Winter} \\
    \hline
    1. Literature review & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} \\
    \hline
    2. Courses and workshops & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    3. Comprehensive exam  &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    4. Acquisition of chemical reagents and equipment &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    5. Design of the photocatalytic floating device &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    6. Synthesis of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} composites &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    7. Characterization of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} composites &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    8. Synthesis of \ch{PU/TiO_2/Ag} fibers &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    9. Characterization of \ch{PU/TiO_2/Ag} fibers &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    10. Construction of the photocatalytic floating device &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &       &  \\
    \hline
    11. Photocatalytic floating device tests  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &  \\
    \hline
    12. Article writting and submission &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &       &  \\
    \hline
    13. Thesis writing &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} &  \\
    \hline
    14. Doctoral dissertation defense  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .647,  .647,  .647} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    }
    }
  \label{tab:research_schedule}%
\end{table}%

%\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

produces the table shown in the picture:

[image]

I would like to increase the height of the rows. Is there any package or command that I can use for that? Also, is it possible to set the same width for Summer, Fall, Winter columns?

Comment: Did you try: `\def\arraystretch{1.5}`? Rmemeber to reset the `arraystretch` to 1 after the table (if needed).

Comment: You can use also some like `\extrarowheight 1em` using the array package. For consistency of font sizes, avoid `\scalebox` and just use  `\footnotesize`  or so in the float. For the columns sizes, instead of `c` use some like `p{5em}` or read about the packages tabularx and tabulary.  BTW, what you posted is not  *minimal* example. People will be more prone to help if you remove unnecessary packages, irrelevant code for the problem, (e.g., the code to colorizing cells), and the amount of contents (the  problem could be seen and solved in a much smaller table).

Comment: Off-topic: cleanup your preamble. Many packages are loaded multiple time even with different options.  Package `hyperref` should be loaded last (with few exception).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use of (relative new) package `tabularray` the MWE, which produce above result, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=2.5cm, hmargin=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemformula}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Hoja7'
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\small
\caption{Research schedule for the project.}
\begin{tblr}{hline{2,4-Y}, vline{1,3-Z},
             colspec  = {r @{\ } X[l] *{12}{c}},
               colsep = 3.5pt,
               rowsep=4pt,
             cell{3}{3-14} = {bg=gray8},
             cell{4}{3-5}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{5}{5}    = {bg=gray8},
             cell{6}{4-5}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{7}{4-9}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{8}{4-5}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{9}{5-6}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{10}{7-10}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{11}{8-10}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{12}{9-11}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{13}{11-12}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{14}{5-6, 8-9,11-12}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{15}{12-13}  = {bg=gray8},
             cell{16}{14}  = {bg=gray8},
             row{1,2} = {font=\small\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c} 
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  Activity / Term
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  2022    &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  2023    &   &
                & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  2024    &   &
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  2025    &   &                               \\
    &   & Summer & Fall & Winter 
        & Summer & Fall & Winter 
        & Summer & Fall & Winter 
        & Summer & Fall & Winter \\
    \midrule
1. &    Literature review 
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
2. &    Courses and workshops
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
3. &    Comprehensive exam
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
4. &   Acquisition of chemical reagents and equipment
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
5. &    Design of the photocatalytic floating device
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
6. &    Synthesis of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} composites
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
7. &    Characterization of \ch{TiO_2/Ag} composites
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
8. &    Synthesis of \ch{PU/TiO_2/Ag} fibers
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
9. &    Characterization of \ch{PU/TiO_2/Ag} fibers
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
10. &   Construction of the photocatalytic floating device
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
11. &   Photocatalytic floating device tests
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
12. &   Article writing and submission
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
13. &   Thesis writing
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    \\
14. &   Doctoral dissertation defense
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

As you can observe, In preamble are loaded only to table relevant packages nad `tabularray` libraries. Exception are `siunitx` and `hyperref` which are added only to show how and where to be in your document preamble.